# Can C# methods in child classes have different argument type (that derives from an argument type for a method in parent class)?

Tags: c#, inheritance, inner-classes

Sorry for a badly phrased question.
I'm making some classes that represent a GUI for a simple game. GUI consists of different elements, represented by classes that derive from some common ancestor UIElement.

```
class UIElement
{
    public virtual void Update(UpdateArgs args) { }

    public class UpdateArgs { }
}
```

Each element should contain an Update() method, but for different elements different arguments are needed (i.e. for progress bars there should be some number representing fullness, for buttons some bool that determines if  it's clickable or not, and so on).
So basically I want to be able to override an Update() method, changing its argument type to a type derived from an argument type of an original method, like this:

```
class ProgressBar : UIElement
{
    public override void Update(UpdateArgs args)
    {
        base.Update(args);
        //Set fullness
    }

    public class UpdateArgs : UIElement.UpdateArgs
    {
        double fullness;
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't work, since a compiler cannot find a suitable method to override (because there is no Update() method in parent class which takes a ProgressBar.UpdateArgs object as an argument). Which is understandable, for example I could implement ProgressBar.UpdateArgs class that doesn't derive from UIElement.UpdateArgs, which would cause errors and stuff.

So my question is, how can I implement what I have described above in a smart way? Is there something that behaves like nested classes, but guarantees that if `A : B` then `A.nested : B.nested`?

Comment: No as is. Perhaps you can use generics but you need to rethink the design or use overloaded methods because you can't change the signature of a virtual. If you need help to redesign you need to update the question with more details about the domain, requirements, goals and more code.

Comment: Your design is inherently flawed. See [the Circle-ellipse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle–ellipse_problem), and [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which your design violates. Why do you think it is a good idea to have such an `Update` method in `UIElement`? What do you actually want to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest two solutions.

1. Use casting type

```cs
    class UIElement
    {
        public virtual void Update(UpdateArgs args) { }

        public class UpdateArgs { }
    }

    class ProgressBar : UIElement
    {
        public override void Update(UpdateArgs args)
        {
            base.Update(args);

            if(args is ProgressBarUpdateArgs updateArgs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(updateArgs.Progress);
            }
        }

        public class ProgressBarUpdateArgs : UpdateArgs
        {
            public int Progress { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

2. Use generic

```cs
    class UIElement<T> // or class UIElement<T> where T: UIElement.UpdateArgs
    {
        public virtual void Update(T args) { }

        public class UpdateArgs { }
    }

    class ProgressBar : UIElement<ProgressBar.ProgressBarUpdateArgs>
    {
        public override void Update(ProgressBarUpdateArgs args)
        {
            base.Update(args);

            Console.WriteLine(args.Progress);
        }

        public class ProgressBarUpdateArgs : UpdateArgs
        {
            public int Progress { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Both solutions work but you can choose one depending on your purpose. Sorry, I can't explain here how they work in a short answer but if you have anything to ask, leave a comment beloww

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I understand how they work.